# How can I check whether there is conflict in time from string like 6:00 PM to 9:00 PM

Tags: c#

I am building something like exam datesheet. I'm currently having issues in finding conflicts between time..

I have a List of strings that stores time intervals like-

```
List<string> times = new List<string>();
times.Add("6:00 PM to 9:00 PM");
times.Add("10:00 AM to 1:00 PM");
```

Now suppose, if want to add below time to the list, I first want to check it does not conflict with the time that is already there.

So, in below case, it should not be added.

```
if(NotConflict("5:00 PM to 7:00 PM"))
    times.Add("5:00 PM to 7:00 PM");
```

But the following can be added since there is no conflict.

```
if(NotConflict("2:00 PM to 5:00 PM"))
    times.Add("2:00 PM to 5:00 PM");
```

I cannot use `DateTime` here because it the very old system and time is being stored like above. And it being used at many places.

Comment: you write a parser, and use it.

Comment: You also probably want to use `DateTime` for this rather than strings.

Comment: You should definitively use DateTime (maybe a List<Tupple<DateTime,DateTime>>)

Comment: `DateTime` cannot be used here. That is why I'm having issues.

Comment: @kamalpreet can you clearly explain in the question what your restrictions are (why can't you use DateTime?)

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: When comparing two time ranges there are 6 conditions (1) Time 1 earlier than time 2. (2)  Time 1 starting earlier than time 2 and ending within time 2. (3) Time 1 starting after time 2 and ending before time 2. (4) Time 1 starting during time 2 and ending after time 2. (5) Time 2 starting after time 1 ends. (6) Time 2 starting before Time 1 and ending after Time 2.  You must test all 6 conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
private static Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> ParseDate(string dateTimes)
{
    var split = dateTimes.Split(new[] { " to " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(split[0], "h:mm tt",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var time2 = DateTime.ParseExact(split[1], "h:mm tt",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return Tuple.Create(time1, time2);
}


private static bool NotConflict(IEnumerable<string> times, string time) {
    var incTime = ParseDate(time);

    return !times.Any(t => {
        var parsed = ParseDate(t);


        return incTime.Item1 <= parsed.Item2 && parsed.Item1 <= incTime.Item2;
    });
}

public static void Main()
{
    var times = new List<string>();
    times.Add("6:00 PM to 9:00 PM");
    times.Add("10:00 AM to 1:00 PM");

    Console.WriteLine("No Conflict 5:00 PM to 7:00 PM: {0}", NotConflict(times, "5:00 PM to 7:00 PM"));
    Console.WriteLine("No Conflict 2:00 PM to 5:00 PM: {0}", NotConflict(times, "2:00 PM to 5:00 PM"));
}
```

`ParseDate` will return a formatted tuple with the start and end time in `Item1` and `Item2` respectively. Then you simply use Linq's `Any` function to filter and make sure that you don't return any that fall within the bounds.

See the DotNet fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYRD0D).

Comment: @kamalpreet I've updated my answer, and provided a DotNet fiddle.

Comment: @kamalpreet I just saw your suggested edit. Can I ask why my current code doesn't work?

Comment: If there is an existing time already and we are trying to add same time interval again, it adds it.

Comment: So just add one more simple line.

Comment: Updated my answer @kamalpreet

Comment: @FrankerZ you can use a simpler algorithm when checking for overlap. `incTime.Item1 <= parsed.Item2 && parsed.Item1 <= incTime.Item2 ` which should cover all cases inclusive of same times.

Comment: Meh, it's all apples and oranges. This answer meets all the criteria for answering the question.

Comment: @FrankerZ let me explain where it fails- say `times` only has `times.Add("6:00 PM to 9:00 PM");` now try to run this `Console.WriteLine("No Conflict: {0}", NotConflict(times, "5:00 PM to 9:00 PM"));` and it will give you incorrect result.

Comment: Just a question... Since the list is a collection of strings couldnt you just compare the strings? If the format of the time is the same then if  string1= "6:00 PM to 9:00 PM" string2 ="6:00 PM to 9:00 PM" wouldnt a simple string1.Equals(string2) tell if the the times are equal? or if you have a list of string times already... listofTimes.Contains(string1); If you are looking for overlap then a simple parser would accomplish this.

Comment: @kamalpreet I am confused by what you mean when you say "conflict"...   *Now suppose, if want to add below time to the list, I first want to check it does not conflict with the time that is already there.
So, in below case, it should not be added.*
if(NotConflict("5:00 PM to 7:00 PM"))    times.Add("5:00 PM to 7:00 PM");
*But the following can be added since there is no conflict.*
if(NotConflict("2:00 PM to 5:00 PM"))    times.Add("2:00 PM to 5:00 PM");*      they both look the same to me... why is the 5pm-7pm ok and 2pm-5pm is not ok... where is the conflict?

Comment: Think it as you are creating a exam datesheet. If there is an exam from 5:00 pm to 7:00 PM then same studnet cannot appear for exam in same timing. But appearing in exam in from 2pm to 5pm is ok because that is the free time slot.

Comment: @kamalpreet I've updated my answer with Nkosi's suggestion